# Script execution failed

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have created a script to capture the heap and thread dump of a running java process.

```
#! /bin/bash

myhost=$(uname)

if [ "${myhost}" == "SunOS" ]; then

HEAPLOGS="/export/home/${USER}/applog/heapdump"
THREADLOGS="/export/home/${USER}/applog/threaddump"

elif [ "${myhost}" == "Linux" ]; then

HEAPLOGS="/opt/app/${USER}/applog/heapdump"
THREADLOGS="/opt/app/${USER}/applog/threaddump"

fi

DAY=$(date +%Y.%m.%d)
NOW=$(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S)
EXPIRE=30

echo " Please select your option "
echo
echo " Heap-Dump : 0 "
echo " Thread-Dump : 1 "
echo " Both of above : 2 "

read hoption


echo
echo " Enter PID :"
read rspid
echo " Enter InstanceName :"
read rspname

case ${hoption} in 

         0)
            # generate java heapdump
              jmap -dump:format=b,file=${HEAPLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.hprof ${rspid}"
              chmod 644 ${HEAPLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.hprof
      ;;
         1)
            # generate java threaddump
              jstack ${rspid} > ${THREADLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.log"
              chmod 644 ${THREADLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.log
      ;;
         2)
            # generate java heapdump
              jmap -dump:format=b,file=${HEAPLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.hprof ${rspid}"
              chmod 644 ${HEAPLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.hprof
            # generate java threaddump
              jstack ${rspid} > ${THREADLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.log"
              chmod 644 ${THREADLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.log
      ;;

esac
```

But my script fails for case statement without throwing any error. I believe `${hoption}` is not getting evaluated.

Comment: You can execute your script with `bash -x` to get some debugging output. And you can add a "catch all" case to your case statement just before `esac`. Something like `*) echo Error hoption="$hoption" >&2; exit 1;;`

Comment: First of all remove the space in #!/bin/bash, it will be interpreted as the interpreter is (space)/bin/bash, it is not broking your script, but can broken if your default shell is sh instead of bash, and in second add the command set -x on the start to debug your script. And post the dump!

Comment: The double quotes ( " ) character at the end of my jmap and jstack command was the culprit here. After removing, my script started working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reading `hoption`, `rspid` and `rspname` from stdin while the script is running, you should take them as options on the command line, just like most other programs do.  This sounds difficult, but is actually quite easy using the bash-builtin `getopts` (see `help getopts` for a summary)

That way you can easily test your script with the same args just by using your shell's command-line history (i.e. NOT have to type in the same values again and again) and, more importantly, you can easily use this script in other scripts, just by calling it with the right args.

Here's a version which does that (plus a few minor improvements.  And fixes to the variable quoting - notice how every time i've *used* a variable, I have enclosed it in double-quotes?  You should too.)

```bash
#! /bin/bash

case "$(uname)" in
   Linux) APPPATH='/opt/app/' ;;
   SunOS) APPPATH='/export/home/' ;;
       *) echo "Unknown OS" >/dev/stderr ; exit 1 ;;
esac

HEAPLOGS="$APPPATH/${USER}/applog/heapdump"
THREADLOGS="$APPPATH/${USER}/applog/threaddump"

DAY=$(date +%Y.%m.%d)
NOW=$(date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S)
EXPIRE=30

usage() {
  [ -z "$*" ] || printf "%s\n\n" "$@"

  cat <<__EOF__
Usage: $0 <-h|-t|-b> -e <expire> -p <pid> -i <instance>

  -h    Heap-Dump
  -t    Thread-Dump
  -b    Both of above

  -e    Expiry time (defaults to 30)

  -p    PID
  -i    Instance Name

__EOF__

exit 1
}

unset hoption rspid rspname

# process command line options
while getopts 'htbe:p:i:' opt ; do
  case "$opt" in
    h|t|b) [ -z "$hoption" ] && hoption="$opt" || \
           usage "Only use one of -h, -t, or -b"
           ;;

    e) EXPIRE="$OPTARG" ;;

    p) rspid="$OPTARG" ;;
    i) rspname="$OPTARG" ;;

    *) usage ;;
  esac
done

[ -z "$hoption" ] && usage "Must provide one of -h, -t, or -b"
[ -z "$rspid" ] && usage "'-p <PID>' is required"
[ -z "$rspname" ] && usage "'-i <instance>' is required"

case "$hoption" in
  h)  # generate java heapdump
      jmap -dump:format=b,file="${HEAPLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.hprof" "${rspid}"
      chmod 644 "${HEAPLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.hprof"
        ;;

  t) # generate java threaddump
     jstack "${rspid}" > "${THREADLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.log"
     chmod 644 "${THREADLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.log"
     ;;


  b) # generate java heapdump
     jmap -dump:format=b,file="${HEAPLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.hprof" "${rspid}"
     chmod 644 "${HEAPLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.hprof"

     # generate java threaddump
     jstack "${rspid}" > "${THREADLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.log"
     chmod 644 "${THREADLOGS}/${rspname}-${NOW}.log"
     ;;
esac
```

Comment: Very nice rewrite.  But, wouldn't it be better to use lowercase variable names, given that none of them are ever exported (so they're not environment variables)?

Comment: @Wildcard probably, but I didn't want to change anything about the script except to fix obvious errors and to change how user-input was handled.  there's enough for Naresh to learn here without the script being changed beyond recognition.

Comment: Fair enough.  :)  I really like how you handled mutually exclusive options—I'll be following that approach.

Comment: @Wildcard - yeah, well, the other alternative was to make $hoption an array (`h|t) hoption+=("$opt") ;;`, either dump the `-b` option or make it set `hoption=(h t)`, and then loop through `"$hoption[@]"` for the final `case` statement.  I took the easier path, partly from laziness, partly from not wanting to make too many potentially-confusing changes to the script at once.

Comment: @cas : I already have a perl script that displays running jvm processes (pid & InstanceName) before the second case statement get executed (not mentioned here). My primary intention was to make the script interactive, for non-technical audience in my case.

Comment: IMO patronising your non-technical audience does them no favours, it's better to teach them basic things (like how command-line options work) that they can re-use with many other programs.  Put more detailed help and explanations in the `usage()` function if necessary but remember that they're not stupid, just lacking in some knowledge or understanding.

Comment: btw, another option is to use `select` (bash builtin) or [iselect](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/tool/iselect/) to allow your users to just select the pid and instance name from a numbered menu (select) or with cursor keys (iselect).  populate select/iselect with the ouput of your perl script.  `iselect` is available pre-packaged for debian and other distros.

Answer (score 1):

Add a debug line of `echo ${hoption}` after it reads it in to confirm it is being set correctly. 
Also put an echo in each case indicating you've reached that case.

In this case since you are only looking for a single character, I would use read in this way:

```
read -r -n 1 hoption
```

The `-n 1` flag tells read to only wait for 1 character and not wait for a new line. the `-r` flag disables special character treatment. In general you should always use `-r` unless you have an explicit reason not to - odd behavior can result otherwise.

I tested the script and it does appear to be getting the value of hoption, at least in my environment (without any changes). If the above doesn't address your issue, what is the error message you are getting?